# Permission denied starting Cordapp via systemctl

Tags: corda

Starting the example cordapp on Ubuntu as a service per: https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.1/deploying-a-node.html

On running the node I get the following error:

```
Apr 25 17:48:04 single-node-marketplace-master systemd[1]: Started Cordapp Example - party B.
Apr 25 17:48:22 single-node-marketplace-master java[99477]: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
Apr 25 17:48:22 single-node-marketplace-master java[99477]:         at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
Apr 25 17:48:22 single-node-marketplace-master java[99477]:         at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
Apr 25 17:48:22 single-node-marketplace-master java[99477]:         at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.enforceSingleNodeIsRunning(NodeStartup.kt:226)
Apr 25 17:48:22 single-node-marketplace-master java[99477]:         at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:53)
Apr 25 17:48:22 single-node-marketplace-master java[99477]:         at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cordapp is being started as the "corda" user. Ensure that you've both created the user and set the permission in `/opt/<cordapp name>`

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --group corda
sudo chown corda:corda /opt/partyB
```